# Dell b1160w not working in 14.04

Tags: drivers, printing, dell

I originally installed the dell b1160w printer on ubuntu 12.04. It worked as expected. A few months ago I upgraded to ubuntu 14.04 64 bit and now I can't get the printer to work. I looked at the driver information on the dell site. They have not updated their driver since 2013 so 12.04 is the latest version with a supported driver.

Is there a work around for this problem, like a generic driver that I can use or a way to install whatever printer interface ubuntu 12.04 was using?

I have a windows virtual box. I can get it to work through there, but it's inconvenient to pull up my virtual box and transfer the files over to it anytime I want to print.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? same problem here, can't get it to work over wifi.  It's working with the usb cable though.

Comment: Finally doesn't work over usb cable, don't know why :/

Ended up setting up an Ubuntu 11.04 virtual box image. I downloaded it from here : http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualboximage/files/Ubuntu%20Linux/11.04/ubuntu_11.04-x86.7z/download (user / passwd : ubuntu / reverse). I've set up a shared folder and I can print without too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the driver (B1160w_Linux_v1.04_Driver from the dell site) on a fresh 14.04 machine. The printer worked without a problem.

Hope that helps.

Comment: AU encourages [high-quality answers](/help/how-to-answer). You're only offering a rough sketch of your solution. Can you please elaborate and describe it with more detail? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded this 1.04 version and then installed it as follows using the Terminal. It seems to be working.

```
cd
cd Downloads
gunzip B1160w_Linux_v1.04_Driver.tar.gz 
tar -xvf B1160w_Linux_v1.04_Driver.tar 
cd cdroot
cd Linux/
sudo ./install.sh
```

Comment: you can skip the `gunzip` command, when you use `tar xzvf` in the next command. The `z` flag for `tar` makes it piping through gzip automatically